# Swift - Cache API response and Request using URLCache not working?

Tags: swift, networking, caching, urlsession

I'm having a GET API that has all the needed headers for enabling caching, also I have handled everything on the client side but am still not able to cache any response for any request.

**Server Response:**

```
 { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "public, max-age=36000"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        1189111
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 26 Dec 2022 19:37:39 GMT"
    );
    Etag =     (
        "W/\"1224f7-5E3fHK2fTHfmdryKk2ICR7b/pS8\""
    );
    Expires =     (
        "Tue, 27 Dec 2022 05:37:38 GMT"
    );
    Via =     (
        "1.1 3fd7afcdda21f0b562dfcbf7920c44a0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
    );
    "x-amz-apigw-id" =     (
        "dxOwXHGSFiAFp7A="
    );
    "x-amz-cf-id" =     (
        "07vEVC3wQGwJGL9RRczVlqi8-28NcLtt78_RkDKp7IZAr6BTSTjvcg=="
    );
    "x-amz-cf-pop" =     (
        "FRA60-P2"
    );
    "x-amzn-remapped-connection" =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "x-amzn-remapped-content-length" =     (
        1189111
    );
    "x-amzn-remapped-date" =     (
        "Mon, 26 Dec 2022 19:37:39 GMT"
    );
    "x-amzn-remapped-server" =     (
        "nginx/1.22.0"
    );
    "x-amzn-requestid" =     (
        "f439b2e9-3f70-4953-8bf2-f2b0114fc572"
    );
    "x-cache" =     (
        "Miss from cloudfront"
    );
    "x-powered-by" =     (
        Express
    );
} }


class CacheManager {
    static let shared = CacheManager()
    let cache: URLCache

    private init() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let cacheDir = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cache")
        cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 16 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 80 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: cacheDir.path)
    }
}

func fetch(filters:[String:Any] = [:], completion: @escaping (Result<[Model], Error>) -> Void) {
    
    
     
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.urlCache = CacheManager.shared.cache
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad

    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    
    let url = URL(string: apiURL)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url , cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad)

   
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.timeoutInterval = 60
    

    if let cachedResponse = CacheManager.shared.cache.cachedResponse(for: request) {
        // Use the cached response
        print("Cache hit! Data: \(cachedResponse.data)")
    } else {
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let dataa = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("Invalid data or response")
                return
            }
            
            if response.statusCode == 200 {
                if let cacheControl = response.allHeaderFields["Cache-Control"] as? String, cacheControl.contains("max-age") {
                    print("Response is cacheable")
                } else {
                    print("Response is not cacheable")
                }
                
                // Check the cache policy of the request
                if request.cachePolicy == .useProtocolCachePolicy || request.cachePolicy == .returnCacheDataElseLoad {
                    print("Request cache policy allows the use of cached data")
                } else {
                    print("Request cache policy does not allow the use of cached data")
                }

                // Cache the response
                // Try to store the response in the cache
                let userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any] = ["key": "value"]
                let cachedResponse = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: dataa, userInfo: userInfo, storagePolicy: .allowed)
                CacheManager.shared.cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedResponse, for: request)
               

            } else {
                print("API error: \(response.statusCode)")
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                } else if let data = data {
                    do {
                        completion(.success(try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data).Model))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You need to reuse the URLSession object. Create it once (using a URLCache), keep a reference to it, and perform all your requests using the same URLSession object which should share the same URL cache.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper but I thought I'm doing a cache implementation that will survive after the app restarted. ( URLCache with specific path)

One more thing that I may be not clear about -> storeCachedResponse return 0 elements -> so no saving happening to retrieve

Comment: There might be an issue with the path. Can you please check the location where the cache is actually created. Unfortunately, the documentation is too vague about the parameter `path`. `path` might be treated like a [relative URL reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2), where the implementation uses an internal "hidden" base URL, where the specified path is applied, or it may allow you to specifiy a full path. As far as I remember, it has some notion if a "hidden base URL" where your path is added to.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in my second comment, I suspect an issue with the path. The code below may track down some issues with a URLCache:

Below is a convenience initialiser which prints memory and disk usage and the location where the cache has been created, making an assumption where it *should* be located. It also has a feature where you can clear the URLCache when running the app from Xcode.

So, when you create a URLCache it will create the persistent store in a certain predefined location (where caches are usually located) and where your "path" is added as a path parameter. Specifically, you should not use the "documentsDirectory" as path, because the whole path will be added to this base location for caches. It's sufficient to use a single path component, for example "myCachePath":

```
self.init(
    memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity,
    diskCapacity: diskCapacity,
    diskPath: "myCachePath"
)
```

See below for where the cache is actually created.

Hope it helps! ;)

```
import Foundation
import os

extension URLCache {
    /// Adds  logging functionality to URLCache creation and an
    /// option to clear the cache via an application launch
    /// parameter `ClearURLCache`.
    convenience init(
        memoryCapacity: Int,
        diskCapacity: Int,
        directoryPath: String = "default"
    ) {
        // create the cache with the specified path:
        self.init(
            memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity,
            diskCapacity: diskCapacity,
            diskPath: directoryPath
        )

        // Now, figure out where it has been created, making some
        // assumptions which has been figured out with trial and error:
        let cachesDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
            .cachesDirectory,
            .userDomainMask,
            true
        ).first!
        let defaultBasePathDir = "\(cachesDirectory)/\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)/"
        let defaultBaseUrlDir = URL(
            fileURLWithPath: defaultBasePathDir,
            isDirectory: true,
            relativeTo: nil
        )
        let directoryUrl = URL(
            fileURLWithPath: directoryPath,
            isDirectory: true,
            relativeTo: defaultBaseUrlDir
        )

        // Assert that our assumption is true:
        assert(
            FileManager.default.fileExists(
                atPath: directoryUrl.path
            ),
            "directory \"\(directoryUrl.path)\"does not exist"
        )

        // Log some useful information:
        let currentDiskUsage = self.currentDiskUsage
        os_log(
            "URLCache created with %@ memory capacity, %@ diskCapacity at URL %@\nCurrent disk usage: %@ ",
            log: URLCacheLog,
            type: .info,
            ByteCountFormatter.string(
                fromByteCount: Int64(memoryCapacity),
                countStyle: .memory
            ),
            ByteCountFormatter.string(
                fromByteCount: Int64(diskCapacity),
                countStyle: .file
            ),
            directoryUrl.path,
            ByteCountFormatter.string(
                fromByteCount: Int64(currentDiskUsage),
                countStyle: .file
            )
        )

        // Clear the cache when a launch parameter "ClearUrlCache" is present
        // (only works when starting from Xcode):
        if ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.filter({ $0.lowercased() == "clearurlcache" }).first != nil {
            os_log("Clearing URLCache", log: URLCacheLog, type: .info)
            self.removeAllCachedResponses()
        }
    }
}

private var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
private let URLCacheLog = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "URLCache")
```